# При попытке установить PyInstaller: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-sjdbhp/pyinstaller/

Tags: python, linux-mint, pyinstaller

Пытаюсь установить PyInstaller на Linux Mint, но при этом возникает ошибка. Прошу помощи с этим вопросом.

root@inspiron:/home# pip install pyinstaller
Collecting pyinstaller
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/3c/c9/c3f9bc64eb11eee6a824686deba6129884c8cbdf70e750661773b9865ee0/PyInstaller-3.6.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "", line 1, in 
    ImportError: No module named setuptools

```
----------------------------------------
```

Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-2h1D8o/pyinstaller/

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55490201/command-python-setup-py-egg-info-failed-with-error-code-1-in-tmp-pip-build-tu

Comment: `pip install mysqlclient `?

Answer (score 0):

Итак, для начала вы используете mint, не забывайте, что на линукс стоит отдельно `python2` и `python3` возможно вы хотели использовать именно python 3?

если вы хотите установить PyInstaller для python 3 то вам нужно использовать `pip3`, а не `pip`

судя по

```py
Traceback (most recent call last): File "", line 1, in ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

python не может найти модуль setuptools, попробуйте установить его:

`pip3 install --upgrade setuptools` - для python 3

`pip install --upgrade setuptools` - для python 2

теперь установим pyinstaller:

`pip3 install pyinstaller --no-cache-dir` - для python 3

`pip install pyinstaller --no-cache-dir` - для python 2

P.S. `--no-cache-dir` заставит pip не использовать уже скачаный pyinstaller, а скачать его полностью заново